# IE8 crashes when styling input[type=submit] with CSS3 PIE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, css, css3pie

Sometimes the page works and you need to refresh the page to see it crash.

You can see a live sample here: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/account/ (ie7 works fine, I am not supporting ie6)

I am attempting to style my submit button with the following values:

```
a.button, input.button {
    border: 2px solid #3A90A7;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #202D32;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 2.6em;
    line-height: 2.6em;
    margin: 0.667em 0.333em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button:hover, input.button:hover{
    border: #202d32 solid 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 3px #FFFFFF inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 3px #FFFFFF inset;
}

input[type=submit] {
    behavior: url(http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/PIE.htc);
    position: relative;
    -pie-poll:true;
}

a.button:hover, input.button:hover{
    -pie-box-shadow: none;
}

.button {
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
}

.button.active {
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #b7b7b7 0%,#b7b7b7 8%,#e5e5e5 8%,#ffffff 100%);
}
```

Finally, the submit button in all it's glory:

```
<input id="submitbtn" class="button omega" type="submit" value="Create your account" name="submit">
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this crash? I don't get any information apart from a script is causing the page to run slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more testing I found the answer to this problem, it wasn't the fact that it was submit button but that it was some kind of form button and I gave it `font-size`.

If I remove the `font-size` property on the element then IE8 stops crashing and I'm a happy bunny.

Apologies as I didn't include the part of the CSS which had the font-size (It's a big file, I glazed over it).

Comment: Thanks, now we know that font-size might cause IE8 to crash when used with CSS3PIE. Gonna run a test to confirm that issue and report to CSS3PIE if it's reproducible.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Specifically it may be font-size on form button-like elements, I was also using ems for font-size but ems that convert to whole pixel values cause a crash also. The crash also happened when the submit button was a button type input element.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I discovered that my button did not work in IE8 beacuse I needed one of the borders to be `none` and this crashed my CSS3PIE. I changed from `border-left: none;` to `border-left-width: 0;` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna check and test but first you need to know some stuff about CSS3PIE

CSS3PIE uses VML -vector markup language- that allows you to draw graphics using Javascript, and it includes functions to create popular CSS3 like effects but limited.

Because it uses Javascript to draw the graphics, It utilize a lot of the browser resources and cause it to hang and eventually crash.

I was using CSS3PIE before but I dropped it after reading this [impressive analogy by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/tiered-adaptive-front-end-experiences/). You should focus on adapting your design to gracefully degrade on IE. It would be better if you used something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for the missing features in the browser and add specific styling to it.

Will be back after testing

**Update**

I tested in IE8 and yes it crashes. There's nothing you can go for I think :(

I would recommend you fallback for a solid light grey color or use a background gradient image.

Comment: Thanks ahmad, I do employ graceful degradation (if you disable js it falls back to the solid color) and I use CSS3PIE rather sparingly, however the majority of my visitors are on ie7 - ie8 and I would really like to provide a better experience for them. It only crashes when rendering on that element, otherwise it works fine. Something to do with `input[type=submit]`

Comment: That's great I didn't realize that. attribute selectors is buggy on IE7-8 as far as I know can you try to attach a class to it and see if it still crashes?

Comment: With a class it also crashes, I think it has to do more with the fact the element is of type submit not the way it is selected. I know people successfully style submit buttons with PIE however.

Comment: can you change it from input to button ? or this is generated using CMS and you cannot modify?

Comment: Just letting you know I found the real problem, thanks for your help.